# how to deploy node server on CPANEL?

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I want to deploy node server over CPANEL how do i start?,  I have searched but not relevant answer entertained me tell me solution if anyone did this.

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

**How to install Node.js and NPM on cPanel Hosting Server**

Node.js currently only works on servers running CentOS 6 or CentOS 7. To determine the CentOS version on your server, run this command:

```
uname -r
```

If the output from this command contains el6 (for example, 2.6.32-531.17.1.lve1.2.60.el6.x86_64) or el7 (for example, 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.12.el7.x86_64) , then your server is running CentOS 6 or CentOS 7. However, if you see el5h (for example, 2.6.32-531.23.3.lve1.2.66.el5h.x86_64), then your server is running CentOS 5 and does not support Node.js.

Download NodeJS. To make sure you’re in the root directory, run this command:

```
cd ~
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v10.15.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

Extract the NodeJS Files:

```
tar xvf node-v10.15.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
```

Now rename the folder to nodejs name, to do this type the following command:

```
mv node-v10.15.0-linux-x64 nodejs
```

Now install node and npm binaries, type the next commands:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cp nodejs/bin/node ~/bin
cd ~/bin  ln -s ../nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm
```

Node.js and npm are installed on your account. To verify, type the following commands:

```
node --version  
npm --version
```

**STOPPING A NODE.JS APPLICATION**

To stop a currently running Node.js application, type the following command:

```
pkill node
```

This command immediately stops all running Node.js applications.